# Symfony 2 and Doctrine2 not loading full entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Could anyone tell me why with this code:

```
<?php
public function continentAndCountriesAction()
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $manager->getRepository('FkgDemoBundle:Continent');
    $europeEntity = $repository->findOneByName('Europe');

    if (!$europeEntity) {
        $europeEntity = new Continent();
        $europeEntity->setName('Europe');
        $manager->persist($europeEntity);
    }

    $countries = array('Poland', 'Germany', 'Czech Republic', 'Italy', 'France');
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        $country = new Country();
        $country->setName($country);
        $country->setContinent($europeEntity);
        $manager->persist($country);
    }

    $manager->flush();

    $entities = $repository->findAll();
    return $this->render('FkgDemoBundle:Default:continent.html.twig', compact('entities'));
}
```

I have in views only "Europe" (Continent) displayed but if I remove saving entities to database like below:

```
<?php
public function continentAndCountriesAction()
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $manager->getRepository('FkgDemoBundle:Continent');
    $europeEntity = $repository->findOneByName('Europe');

    if (!$europeEntity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Continent not found.');

    $entities = $repository->findAll();
    return $this->render('FkgDemoBundle:Default:continent.html.twig', compact('entities'));
}
```

everything is loaded as I expected - Europe with countries?

Profiler gives me 12 Queries while inserting http://screencast.com/t/MZuTdUHJIJc and having last query (findAll()) like this http://screencast.com/t/dfDSprfjV9y
but if I don't save entities findAll() result is different: http://screencast.com/t/KoCZcsp00th.

Is something "magic" in loading Entities with Doctrine2?
Symfony 2.3.7
Doctrine 2.3.4

Comment: Please separate the code to insert and view entities, this doesn't help you. I suppose that once the $Europe* continent is added in the database you won't have to insert again?

Comment: It will be easier to debug if your code only get data, without adding it just before.

Comment: I know that code should be separated but I'm currently just trying to learn Symfony and I want to avoid jumping between many files. I was experimenting with simple table 1:n relation - not real application. 
I have truncated everything so $Europe isn't added yet.